# Which FIR filter should I choose?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, stft

If I have the following spectrogram:

[image]

And only wanted to have the signals that are in a particular frequency range (2627 - 3939htz).. Can I run a FIR filter to only allow these signals through, and therefore, it will be much easier to segment each of the calls?

If so, which FIR filter would be more appropriate for this task? Would a band-pass filter work for this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A spectrogram is already a bunch of magnitudes of bandpass filtered signal, especially if a non-rectangular window has been applied before the STFTs.   You might be able to test whether a higher quality bandpass filter might help by just keeping the horizontal rows of your spectrogram that correspond to the frequencies you want to keep for your segmentation.

Comment: I've just realised this, thank you. Ok can you suggest any reading material at all which could help in segmenting the spectrogram? I've tried PCA / ICA and can't figure out a way to threshold the data and calculate the energy. Anything will be greatly apprciciated